# AngularJS custom directive don't generate the code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS and, seeing all my html code becoming more massive and dirty, I wanted to do directives to organize it. So, I started by a little directive that you can see here:

```
app.module('MyDirectiveModule', [ ])

.directive('TestDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'test-index.html'
  };
});
```

for this little piece of code:

```
  <div class="text-center">
      <h1>Coding with AngularJs</h1><br><br>
  </div>
```

so the final result is (the html directive file is test-index.html):

```
<body ng-app="testsApp">

  <test-index></test-index>
```

I include all the scripts and I have checked all the paths, I still don't understand why it still doesn't work..

Comment: change your directive name to testIndex instead of TestDirective. It will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
<body ng-app="testsApp">
```

which means you should have a `testsApp` module. If you do, it should depend on `MyDirectiveModule`, which your directive is in.

```
angular.module('testsApp', ['MyDirectiveModule']);
```

If you don't have a `testsApp` module, then replace your ng-app value to the directive module:

```
<body ng-app="MyDirectiveModule">
```

And as @Baruch mentions, your directive's element should be changed to this:

```
<test-directive></test-directive>
```

Comment: That was the problem, thanks (and the directive name, it must have a lowercase first character), now i have a template load error, but I think it is a parth problem

Answer (score 3):

You're calling your directive using `<test-index></test-index>` but your directive's name is `TestDirective`. You should call it using `<test-directive></test-directive>`

Also, if you're using Angular 1.5 I recommend you look into components instead of directives. It will make the transition to Angular2 a lot smoother.